# How to use code contracts when deriving from interfaces like IDictionary<T, U>?

Tags: c#, interface, code-contracts

One class I am writing implements `IDictionary<string, object>`. In my `CopyTo` implementation, I would like to use code contracts: stuff like `Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(array != null)`.

But, I get this warning (with some namespaces removed for readability):

Method '`LuaDictionary.CopyTo(KeyValuePair<String,Object>[],Int32)`' implements interface method '`ICollection<KeyValuePair<String,Object>>.CopyTo(KeyValuePair<String,Object>[],Int32)`', thus cannot add `Requires`.

I see that there are some related questions, but they all seem to have to do with interfaces that are under the user's control. Obviously, `IDictionary<T, U>` is not under my control, so I can't annotate it with `ContractClassFor` or anything like that.

So am I just unable to use code contracts here? If so... major bummer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a bummer, but is understandable because client code that uses instances of your class as `IDictionary<string, object>` should not have to meet preconditions that are not expected of `IDictionary<string, object>`.

You can read the answer provided to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414586/code-contracts-typeimplements-interface-method-interface-method-thus-cannot-a), which links to and quotes the Code Contracts User Manual, and you can look at [this article](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/net/code-contracts-preview-interfaces.aspx), which explains the situation this way, and goes on to provide a simple example:

> Note that the Liskov's substitution principle holds true for Code Contracts in much the same way it holds for plain classes. The Liskov's principles says the following:
>
> *Subclasses should always be substitutable for their base classes.*
>
> In terms of the Code Contracts API this means that a derived class (or a class that implements a contract-based interface) should not expect more preconditions as the parent.

Answer (score 5):

Keep in mind that `IDictionary<K,V>` already has that `Requires` :)

You can view the existing contracts DLLs for classes under: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Contracts`.

If you open `mscorlib.Contracts.dll` using Reflector you can view the contracts for the collection classes; `CopyTo` has the following:

```
public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
{
    Contract.Requires((bool)(array != null), null, "array != null");
    Contract.Requires((bool)(arrayIndex >= 0), null, "arrayIndex >= 0");
    Contract.Requires((bool)((arrayIndex + this.Count) <= array.Length), null, "arrayIndex + this.Count  <= array.Length");
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that this information is now visible using the "Code Contracts Editor Extensions" plugin for VS: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/85f0aa38-a8a8-4811-8b86-e7f0b8d8c71b/